# Как поместить результат Promise (JS) в переменную?

Tags: javascript, promise, knex.js

Как поместить результат промиса в переменную? Мне надо что-то вроде этого:

```
var users = knex('users').then();
var cats= knex('categories').then();
var prods = knex('products').then();

res.render('index.ejs', {
   'users': users,
   'cats': cats,
   'prods': prods
});
```

Данный код не работает, в переменных users, cats, prods не массив или объект, а такой же промис.

Answer (score -1):

```
let users, cats, prods;
knex('users').then(resp => users = resp);
knex('categories').then(resp => categories = resp);
knex('products').then(resp => products = resp);
res.render('index.ejs', {
    'users': users,
    'cats': cats,
    'prods': prods
});
```

Comment: А в чём смысл такого варианта, если в `res.render` попадёт 3 значения `undefined`? Ведь корректные значения переменным присваиваются в `then`, а значит, асинхронно и позже.

Comment: @Regent вопрос был не об этом  Добавьте свой вариант

Comment: тут нужен Promise.all или тупо цепочка обещаний, а не эти костыли